# How to add header and rownames to ts

Tags: r, time-series

if I print to console

> AirPassengers

I is nicely formated with header and row names, why following code is not also siniliary formated?

```
as.ts(
  read.zoo(
    data.frame(
      date = seq(Sys.Date()-365, Sys.Date(), by = "day"),
      value = seq(1, 366)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the read.zoo function, it resturns a zoo object, which is a type of character.

If you get rid of the function you get:

```
as.ts(
    data.frame(
      date = seq(Sys.Date()-365, Sys.Date(), by = "day"),
      value = seq(1, 366)
    )
)
```

You should get a time series object that is a matrix format

If you must use read.zoo

```
ts <- as.ts(
  zoo::read.zoo(df)
  ) |> data.frame() |> setNames(names(df[2]))
)
```

Comment: I have used that, but this way is date converted to number and it object still doesnt contain rownames and colnames.

Comment: Ok. It makes sense now, you want the row names to be dates.  I personally like the xts package, you can simply replace as.ts with as.xts ```xts::as.xts(
      read.zoo(
    data.frame(
      date = seq(Sys.Date()-365, Sys.Date(), by = "day"),
      value = seq(1, 366)
    ) 
  )
) ```  You can then easily change the name as you like